SQL join: unnesting rows with same column names (but different data) without resorting to aliases
Let's say I have three tables:
t1:



client_id
transmission_id
timestamp
column_A




1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:31:27
Banana


1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:31:27
Citrus


2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:12:14
Apple



t2:



client_id
transmission_id
timestamp
column_B




1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:41:27
Paris


1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:41:27
London


2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:22:14
NY



t3:



client_id
transmission_id
timestamp
column_C




1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:31:27
Eat


1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:31:27
Pray


2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:12:14
Love



You might notice that while client_id, transmission_id and timestamp (which I previously used as join keys) match for t1 and t3, timestamp data doesn't match in t2.
I'd like to join these tables such that the differences in timestamp data would be unnested into different rows:



client_id
transmission_id
timestamp
column_A
column_B
column_C




1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:31:27
Banana

Eat


1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:41:27

Paris



1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:31:27
Citrus

Pray


1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:41:27

London



2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:12:14
Apple

Love


2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:22:14

NY




Unfortunately I'm a bit stumped on how to do that.
I have tried using aliases to map different timestamps to their own columns (as joining the data without the timestamp as key results in ambiguity), such as this:



client_id
transmission_id
t1_t3.timestamp
t2.timestamp
column_A
column_B
column_C




1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:31:27
2024-10-16 10:41:27
Banana
Paris
Eat


1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:31:27
2024-10-16 11:41:27
Citrus
London
Pray


2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:12:14
2024-10-16 09:22:14
Apple
NY
Love



But my wish is to have a single timestamp column as it's difficult to follow the "timeline" beyond this toy example.

tag your database as well

You'll only want to join the tables. You need full outer joins in this situation.
select *
from t1
full outer join t2 using (client_id, transmission_id, timestamp)
full outer join t3 using (client_id, transmission_id, timestamp)
order by client_id, transmission_id, timestamp;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/VId3eW9t

Suggested answer seems to generalize well for the real-life version of this problem, offers the desired result and is elegant, thank you for your help

you need to do this :
select client_id,transmission_id,timestamp 
  , max(column_A) as column_A
  , max(column_b) as column_B 
  , max(column_C) as column_C
from (
  select client_id,transmission_id,timestamp,column_A, null as column_B, null as column_c from t1
  union all 
  select client_id,transmission_id,timestamp,null as column_A, column_B, null as column_c from t2
  union all 
  select client_id,transmission_id,timestamp,null as column_A, null as column_B, column_c from t3
)
group by client_id,transmission_id,timestamp

output :



client_id
transmission_id
timestamp
column_a
column_b
column_c




1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:31:27
Banana
null
Eat


1
AAA1
2024-10-16 10:41:27
null
Paris
null


1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:31:27
Citrus
null
Pray


1
AAA2
2024-10-16 11:41:27
null
London
null


2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:12:14
Apple
null
Love


2
BBB1
2024-10-16 09:22:14
null
NY
null



fiddle

Unfortunately in the real-life version of the problem there are way more than a single column per joined table I want to see in the result, I'd like a solution where I wouldn't need to specify which need to be null and which not in regards to union all

@Shotey Then give a proper real-life example.  The answer given here definitely satisfy your sample data posted.

@Eric I'm sure you can understand that in some cases it's not possible to share exactly what you're working on (given that the query might be complex and 100+ lines long or due to other reasons) and I'm sure you can understand that hardcoding every column if it needs to be null or not (if union all approach was to be taken) might not feasible or does not contribute to readability at all.
The answer was to simply use full outer join.

@Shotey you could mention it in your question at least , also then accept Thorston answer
